# Definition of boundary of differential manifold is well defined

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, manifolds-with-boundary

Given the following definition of manifold with boundary :

*$S \subset \mathbb{R}^{N}, N \in \mathbb{N}$ is a $n-$differential manifold with boudary if : $n \in \mathbb{N}, \forall \hspace{0.1cm} p \in S, \hspace{0.1cm}\exists \hspace{0.1cm} V $open neighborhood of $p$ in $\mathbb{R}^{N}$ and $U$ open in $\mathbb{R}^n$, with $\varphi : U \longmapsto V \hspace{0.1cm} C^\infty$ with differential of rnk $n$ such that $\varphi(U \cap \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : x_n \geq 0\}) = V \cap S$ is a homeomorphism.
In this setting we say that $\partial S \ni p \iff \varphi(U \cap \{x_n = 0\}) \ni p$*

With definition I'd like to prove the well-definess of the boundary of a manifold, without using arguments which involve algebraic topology.

To be more accurate, it's not clear to me how the following follows from the definition :

If $\varphi_1,\varphi_2$ are parametrization with $ p \in \varphi_1(U \cap \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : x_n \geq 0\}), p \in \varphi_2(U \cap \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : x_n \geq 0\})$ we have that $$p \in \varphi_1(U_1 \cap \{x_n = 0\}) \iff p \in \varphi_2(U_2 \cap \{x_n = 0\})$$

Any help hint or reference of the proof will be appreciated.

Comment: Does [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2546387/confusion-about-definition-of-manifold-with-boundary) answer your question?

Comment: @paulblartmathcop I believe it uses Invariance of domain

Comment: @DIdier_ I'd like to avoid algebraic topology if possible

Comment: @jacopoburelli In the smooth settings, the definition of a diffeomorphism forces the map to be locally open. Thus you can adapt the proof in the link without using the invariance of domain: just use the fact that $\phi$ is open because of its definition.

Comment: @DIdier_ Could you just sketch the points of the proof ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove the consistency of the definition for a point $p$ to be in the boundary, it is equivalent to prove the consistency of the converse, *i.e* the definition for a point to be in the interior of $M$.

Let $p \in M$ and suppose there exists a chart $\varphi : U \to \mathbb{R}^n_+=\{(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\in \mathbb{R}^n~|~x_n \geqslant 0\}$ such that $\varphi(p)_n >0$. Suppose $\psi : V \to \mathbb{R}^n_+$ is another chart with $p \in V$. Let us show that $\psi(p)_n>0$.

By the very definition of charts, $\psi\circ \varphi^{-1} : \varphi(U\cap V) \to \psi (U\cap V)$ is a diffeomorphism. Now, as $\varphi(p)_n>0$, there exists an open subset around $\varphi(p)$ is $\varphi(U\cap V)$ is an open subset $W\subset \varphi(U\cap V)$ such that for all $x \in W$, $x_n>0$ (take an open ball with small enough radius). $W$ is then an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n_+$ such that every $x$ in it has $x_n >0$: it is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Now, extand the codomain of $\psi\circ \varphi^{-1}$ to be all of $\mathbb{R}^n$. We have a map $\psi \circ \varphi^{-1} : W \to \mathbb{R}^n$ which defined on an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and such that it is a diffeomorphism onto its image: its image is thus open because of the inverse function theorem. Therefore, it is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, contained in $\mathbb{R}^n_+$. Consequently, all $x$ in $W$ satisfy $\psi\circ\varphi^{-1}(x)_n >0$. That is, all $q$ in $\varphi^{-1}(W)$ satisfies $\psi(q)_n>0$. Thus, $\psi(p)_n >0$. We have shown that if there exists a chart such that $\varphi(p)_n >0$, then for all chart $\psi$ for which $\psi(p)$ is defined, then $\psi(p)_n>0$.

Conversly, if there exsits a chart for which $\varphi(p)_n = 0$, then for all chart $\psi$ such that $\psi(p)$ is defined, $\psi(p)_n =0$.

**Comment:** this is an exact reformulation of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2546387/confusion-about-definition-of-manifold-with-boundary) but we do not use here the invariance domain theorem because in this context, the fact that a diffeomorphism is open is a straightforward consequence of the inverse function theorem, that is an easier result.

**Edit** It has been asked several times in comments to explain why transition maps of a smooth manifold are diffeomorphisms. This is directly following from the definitions of:

- a diffeomorphism
- the transitions maps

Here is the reason. A diffeomorphism $f : U \to V$ between open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a *smooth homeomorphism* with *smooth inverse*.

The transitions maps are $\varphi_{\alpha\beta} = \varphi_{\beta}\circ {\varphi_{\alpha}}^{-1} : \varphi_{\alpha}(U_{\alpha}\cap U_{\beta}) \to \varphi_{\beta}\left(U_{\alpha}\cap U_{\beta} \right)$ and **by definition**, are *smooth homeomorphisms*. Now, it is straightforward to show that ${\varphi_{\alpha\beta}}^{-1} = \varphi_{\beta\alpha}$ is also a transition function and thus, is a *smooth homeomorphism* **by definition**.

Hence, $\varphi_{\alpha\beta}$ is a *smooth homeomorphism* with *smooth inverse*: it is a diffeomorphism.

Comment: "By the very definition of charts, $\psi\circ \varphi^{-1} : \varphi(U\cap V) \to \psi (U\cap V)$ is a diffeomorphism". Could you briefly explain what you meant ? I don't know hot to affirm that $\psi\circ \varphi^{-1}$ is a diffeomorphism exactcly on $ \varphi(U\cap V) $ and its image since my definition doesn't required it. I do agree that you can shrink it to be, using inverse function theorem.

Comment: A diffeomorphism is a smooth homeomophism with a smooth inverse. A smooth atlas is such that transition functions are homeomorphisms that are... smooth. The symmetry of the definition implies that their inveres are smooth too.

Comment: Some more questions : Why do you invoke the inverse function theorem to prove that is an open map ? Shouldn't be enough the fact that $\psi \circ \phi^{-1}$ is an open map since they are homeomorphism  on the image? And why $W$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ ?

Comment: How does, from the hypotesis, follow that the transition maps are diffeomorphism? It seems to me that they are only homeomorphisms.

Comment: OP, Please try to find by yourself why it is an open subset in $\mathbb{R}^n$. It is not a hard thing to do and I already wrote many details to give you the ideas of the proof. Hint: an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n_+$ that does not meet its boundary is in fact open in $\mathbb{R}^n$.
@AndreaBaleani I added a comment to explain why the transition maps are diffeomorphisms.